# Header photo moving around

Tags: html, css, image, header

I recently received some help to fix an issue with my footer being in the middle of the page (much much appreciated!) but it looks like I have another issue - the photo in my header (supposed to be centered and fixed) is now more to the left and moves when I scroll the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset= "utf-8">
        <Title>Contact</Title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <nav>
  <ul>
    <!-- list item one -->
    <li> 
        <a href="auto2.html">Home</a> 
    </li>
    <!-- list item two -->
    <li> 
        <a href="aboutauto2.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <!-- list item three -->
    <li> 
        <a href="service3.html">Services</a>
    </li>
    <!-- list item four -->
    <li> 
        <a href="contact3.html">Contact</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
 <img src="CG1.svg" alt-text="Collision Guru Logo" width=250px height=80px class="center">
</header>
<h1> Contact Us</h1><div class="form-container">
<div class="form-container">
<img src="yellow car headlight collision.jpg" width=450px height=400px class="carimg">
<form action="C:\Users\elizabeth.sweeney\Downloads\form_data.php" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"> <br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>
  <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br>
  <input type="phone" id="phone" name="phone">
  <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="option1" value="Paint">
  <label for="option1"> Paint Job</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="option2" value="Body">
  <label for="option2"> Body Work</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="option3" value="Clean">
  <label for="option3"> Cleaning</label><br>
  <div class="submitbutton">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>

</form>
</div>


<footer>
<nav>
  <div class="contactinfo">
    440-555-6893 • <a href="mike.tarescavage@gmail.com"> mike.tarescavage@gmail.com</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sociallinks">
        <img src= "facebook-icon.png" width=30px height=30px> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/collision_guru"><img src= "IG-icon-2.png" width=30px height=30px></a>
    </div>
</nav>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
background: #ffffff;
font-family: century gothic;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}

header {
    background: #000000;
    height: 125px;
    color: #ffffff;
    

}

a{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  
  /*this option by default dispose the elements in a row (flex-direction: row)*/
display: flex;
}
li{
  list-style-type: none;  
  
  /*when I specify 2 values to margin, the first one is for the top and bottom side, the second for the left and right side*/
  margin: 0 1vw;
}




.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  }
  h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: century gothic;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}

.form-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
form
{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 75px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
 margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
input[type=email], select {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
 margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
input[type=phone], select {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
 margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
text-align: left;
display: in-line block;
margin-left: 30px;
}
.submitbutton {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 80px;
  display: block;
}
input[type=submit] {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: in-line block;
}


.carimg {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}


footer {
  background: #000000;
  height: 125px;
  color: #ffffff;
  
}
.footerlinks {
  float: left;
  word-spacing: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.contactinfo {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 50%;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 50px;

}
.sociallinks {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
}
```

This happened after adding the form-container class - not sure if that has anything to do with it, or perhaps another step needs to be taken with the photo? Or is it's completely unrelated.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `display: fixed;` applied to your `.center` class which is causing your img element in the header to move with the scrollbar. Removing the `class="center"` attribute from the img element solves the scrolling issue but now your image is positioned slightly to the right of where it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your logo to stay fixed in the top center on scroll, then update the css to be:

```
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: fixed;
 }
```

But if you want it to only be centered on your header, then you just need to remove the `"center"` class form the logo.